# click back button and delay to exit activity android

Tags: android, delay

I have a program that consists of two activities. I go from first activity to the second activity. Then press the Back button,  the program has delay and shows a white screen. How do I destroy delay?
when i click my button do this in First Activity

```
myHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Animation vanish2 =AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this,R.anim.out_to_right);
                    findViewById(R.id.imageView1).startAnimation(vanish2);
                    findViewById(R.id.textView1).startAnimation(vanish2);
                    vanish2.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {


                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {
                            //startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,S1.class));

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
                            t1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            i1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,S1.class));

                            //overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadeout, R.anim.fadein);   
                            //overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_down_in, R.anim.push_down_out);

                        }
                    });
                }
            }, 400);
```

Second Activity have nothing just i want press back button and exit from second activity

this is my whole first activity. by the way I'm beginner in android

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private ViewFlipper viewFlipper;
private float lastX;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DITHER, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DITHER);
    /*requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);*/  
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    EjadeText();
    SabteDataBase();
    viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.view_flipper);
    final ImageView i1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    final ImageView i2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    final ImageView i3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
    final ImageView i4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
    final ImageView i5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
    final TextView t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    final TextView t2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    final TextView t3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    final TextView t4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    final TextView t5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    int a = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;

    if(a!=2)
    {
    i1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {




        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.out_to_right);
            //viewFlipper.showNext();
            Animation vanish =AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this,R.anim.out_to_right);
            findViewById(R.id.imageView5).startAnimation(vanish);
            findViewById(R.id.textView5).startAnimation(vanish);
            vanish.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {


                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {
                    //startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,S1.class));

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
                    i5.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    t5.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                }
            });

            Handler myHandler = new Handler();
            myHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Animation vanish2 =AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this,R.anim.out_to_right);
                    findViewById(R.id.imageView4).startAnimation(vanish2);
                    findViewById(R.id.textView4).startAnimation(vanish2);
                    vanish2.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {


                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {
                            //startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,S1.class));

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
                            i4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            t4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                        }
                    });
                }
            }, 100);

            myHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Animation vanish2 =AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this,R.anim.out_to_right);
                    findViewById(R.id.imageView3).startAnimation(vanish2);
                    findViewById(R.id.textView3).startAnimation(vanish2);
                    vanish2.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {


                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {
                            //startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,S1.class));

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
                            i3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            t3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                        }
                    });
                }
            }, 200);
            myHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Animation vanish2 =AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this,R.anim.out_to_right);
                    findViewById(R.id.imageView2).startAnimation(vanish2);
                    findViewById(R.id.textView2).startAnimation(vanish2);
                    vanish2.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {


                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {
                            //startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,S1.class));

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
                            i2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            t2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                        }
                    });
                }
            }, 300);
            myHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Animation vanish2 =AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this,R.anim.out_to_right);
                    findViewById(R.id.imageView1).startAnimation(vanish2);
                    findViewById(R.id.textView1).startAnimation(vanish2);
                    vanish2.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {


                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {
                            //startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,S1.class));

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
                            t1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            i1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            Intent i = new Intent (MainActivity.this,S1.class);
                            startActivity(i);
                            //startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,S1.class));

                            //overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadeout, R.anim.fadein);   
                            //overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_down_in, R.anim.push_down_out);

                        }
                    });
                }
            }, 400);


        }

    });



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.

    //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{

    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
    case R.id.menu_exit:
        // Single menu item is selected do something
        // Ex: launching new activity/screen or show alert message
        finish();
        return true;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}    


////////baraye neveshtane file bayad dar manifest e barname ejaze dad khte 4
public void EjadeText()
{
    File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File myFile = new File(sdcard,"Mas.txt"); //sabt file to sdcard

    /////////eijade file txt Masirha
    try
    {
        String[] valueS1 = new String[] { "1  -  2  -  3  -  عباس آباد  -  11/02/1392", "4  -  5  -  6  -  سعادت آباد  -  22/03/1392", "1  -  2  -  3  -  عباس آباد  -  11/02/1392", "4  -  5  -  6  -  سعادت آباد  -  22/03/1392",
                "1  -  2  -  3  -  عباس آباد  -  11/02/1392", "4  -  5  -  6  -  سعادت آباد  -  22/03/1392", "1  -  2  -  3  -  عباس آباد  -  11/02/1392", "4  -  5  -  6  -  سعادت آباد  -  22/03/1392",
                "1  -  2  -  3  -  عباس آباد  -  11/02/1392", "4  -  5  -  6  -  سعادت آباد  -  22/03/1392", "1  -  2  -  3  -  عباس آباد  -  11/02/1392", "4  -  5  -  6  -  سعادت آباد  -  22/03/1392",
                "1  -  2  -  3  -  عباس آباد  -  11/02/1392", "4  -  5  -  6  -  سعادت آباد  -  22/03/1392", "1  -  2  -  3  -  عباس آباد  -  11/02/1392", "4  -  5  -  6  -  سعادت آباد  -  22/03/1392",
                "1  -  2  -  3  -  عباس آباد  -  11/02/1392", "4  -  5  -  6  -  سعادت آباد  -  22/03/1392", "1  -  2  -  3  -  عباس آباد  -  11/02/1392", "4  -  5  -  6  -  سعادت آباد  -  22/03/1392",
                "1  -  2  -  3  -  عباس آباد  -  11/02/1392", "4  -  5  -  6  -  سعادت آباد  -  22/03/1392", "1  -  2  -  3  -  عباس آباد  -  11/02/1392", "4  -  5  -  6  -  سعادت آباد  -  22/03/1392",
                "1  -  2  -  3  -  عباس آباد  -  11/02/1392", "4  -  5  -  6  -  سعادت آباد  -  22/03/1392", "1  -  2  -  3  -  عباس آباد  -  11/02/1392", "4  -  5  -  6  -  سعادت آباد  -  22/03/1392",
                "1  -  2  -  3  -  عباس آباد  -  11/02/1392", "4  -  5  -  6  -  سعادت آباد  -  22/03/1392", "1  -  2  -  3  -  عباس آباد  -  11/02/1392", "4  -  5  -  6  -  سعادت آباد  -  22/03/1392",
                "1  -  2  -  3  -  عباس آباد  -  11/02/1392", "4  -  5  -  6  -  سعادت آباد  -  22/03/1392", "1  -  2  -  3  -  عباس آباد  -  11/02/1392", "4  -  5  -  6  -  سعادت آباد  -  22/03/1392",
                "1  -  2  -  3  -  عباس آباد  -  11/02/1392", "4  -  5  -  6  -  سعادت آباد  -  22/03/1392", "1  -  2  -  3  -  عباس آباد  -  11/02/1392", "4  -  5  -  6  -  سعادت آباد  -  22/03/1392",
                "1  -  2  -  3  -  عباس آباد  -  11/02/1392", "4  -  5  -  6  -  سعادت آباد  -  22/03/1392", "1  -  2  -  3  -  عباس آباد  -  11/02/1392", "4  -  5  -  6  -  سعادت آباد  -  22/03/1392",
                "1  -  2  -  3  -  عباس آباد  -  11/02/1392", "4  -  5  -  6  -  سعادت آباد  -  22/03/1392", "1  -  2  -  3  -  عباس آباد  -  11/02/1392", "4  -  5  -  6  -  سعادت آباد  -  22/03/1392",
                "1  -  2  -  3  -  عباس آباد  -  11/02/1392", "4  -  5  -  6  -  سعادت آباد  -  22/03/1392", "1  -  2  -  3  -  عباس آباد  -  11/02/1392", "4  -  5  -  6  -  سعادت آباد  -  22/03/1392",
                "1  -  2  -  3  -  عباس آباد  -  11/02/1392", "4  -  5  -  6  -  سعادت آباد  -  22/03/1392", "1  -  2  -  3  -  عباس آباد  -  11/02/1392", "4  -  5  -  6  -  سعادت آباد  -  22/03/1392",
                "1  -  2  -  3  -  عباس آباد  -  11/02/1392", "4  -  5  -  6  -  سعادت آباد  -  22/03/1392", "1  -  2  -  3  -  عباس آباد  -  11/02/1392", "4  -  5  -  6  -  سعادت آباد  -  22/03/1392",
                "1  -  2  -  3  -  عباس آباد  -  11/02/1392", "4  -  5  -  6  -  سعادت آباد  -  22/03/1392", "1  -  2  -  3  -  عباس آباد  -  11/02/1392", "4  -  5  -  6  -  سعادت آباد  -  22/03/1392",
                "1  -  2  -  3  -  عباس آباد  -  11/02/1392", "4  -  5  -  6  -  سعادت آباد  -  22/03/1392", "1  -  2  -  3  -  عباس آباد  -  11/02/1392", "4  -  5  -  6  -  سعادت آباد  -  22/03/1392",
                "1  -  2  -  3  -  عباس آباد  -  11/02/1392", "4  -  5  -  6  -  سعادت آباد  -  22/03/1392", "1  -  2  -  3  -  عباس آباد  -  11/02/1392", "4  -  5  -  6  -  سعادت آباد  -  22/03/1392",
                "1  -  2  -  3  -  عباس آباد  -  11/02/1392", "4  -  5  -  6  -  سعادت آباد  -  22/03/1392", "1  -  2  -  3  -  عباس آباد  -  11/02/1392", "4  -  5  -  6  -  سعادت آباد  -  22/03/1392",
                "1  -  2  -  3  -  عباس آباد  -  11/02/1392", "4  -  5  -  6  -  سعادت آباد  -  22/03/1392", "1  -  2  -  3  -  عباس آباد  -  11/02/1392", "4  -  5  -  6  -  سعادت آباد  -  22/03/1392",
                "1  -  2  -  3  -  عباس آباد  -  11/02/1392", "4  -  5  -  6  -  سعادت آباد  -  22/03/1392", "1  -  2  -  3  -  عباس آباد  -  11/02/1392", "4  -  5  -  6  -  سعادت آباد  -  22/03/1392",
                "1  -  2  -  3  -  عباس آباد  -  11/02/1392", "4  -  5  -  6  -  سعادت آباد  -  22/03/1392", "1  -  2  -  3  -  عباس آباد  -  11/02/1392", "4  -  5  -  6  -  سعادت آباد  -  22/03/1392",
                "1  -  2  -  3  -  عباس آباد  -  11/02/1392", "4  -  5  -  6  -  سعادت آباد  -  22/03/1392", "1  -  2  -  3  -  عباس آباد  -  11/02/1392", "4  -  5  -  6  -  سعادت آباد  -  22/03/1392",
                "1  -  2  -  3  -  عباس آباد  -  11/02/1392", "4  -  5  -  6  -  سعادت آباد  -  22/03/1392", "1  -  2  -  3  -  عباس آباد  -  11/02/1392", "4  -  5  -  6  -  سعادت آباد  -  22/03/1392",
                "1  -  2  -  3  -  عباس آباد  -  11/02/1392", "4  -  5  -  6  -  سعادت آباد  -  22/03/1392", "1  -  2  -  3  -  عباس آباد  -  11/02/1392", "4  -  5  -  6  -  سعادت آباد  -  22/03/1392",
                "1  -  2  -  3  -  عباس آباد  -  11/02/1392", "4  -  5  -  6  -  سعادت آباد  -  22/03/1392", "1  -  2  -  3  -  عباس آباد  -  11/02/1392", "4  -  5  -  6  -  سعادت آباد  -  22/03/1392",
                "1  -  2  -  3  -  عباس آباد  -  11/02/1392", "4  -  5  -  6  -  سعادت آباد  -  22/03/1392", "1  -  2  -  3  -  عباس آباد  -  11/02/1392", "4  -  5  -  6  -  سعادت آباد  -  22/03/1392",
                "1  -  2  -  3  -  عباس آباد  -  11/02/1392", "4  -  5  -  6  -  سعادت آباد  -  22/03/1392", "1  -  2  -  3  -  عباس آباد  -  11/02/1392", "4  -  5  -  6  -  سعادت آباد  -  22/03/1392",
                "1  -  2  -  3  -  عباس آباد  -  11/02/1392", "4  -  5  -  6  -  سعادت آباد  -  22/03/1392", "1  -  2  -  3  -  عباس آباد  -  11/02/1392", "4  -  5  -  6  -  سعادت آباد  -  22/03/1392",
                "1  -  2  -  3  -  عباس آباد  -  11/02/1392", "4  -  5  -  6  -  سعادت آباد  -  22/03/1392", "1  -  2  -  3  -  عباس آباد  -  11/02/1392", "4  -  5  -  6  -  سعادت آباد  -  22/03/1392",
                "1  -  2  -  3  -  عباس آباد  -  11/02/1392", "4  -  5  -  6  -  سعادت آباد  -  22/03/1392", "1  -  2  -  3  -  عباس آباد  -  11/02/1392", "4  -  5  -  6  -  سعادت آباد  -  22/03/1392",
                "1  -  2  -  3  -  عباس آباد  -  11/02/1392", "4  -  5  -  6  -  سعادت آباد  -  22/03/1392", "1  -  2  -  3  -  عباس آباد  -  11/02/1392", "4  -  5  -  6  -  سعادت آباد  -  22/03/1392"};

        myFile.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
        OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter =new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);


        for (int i=0; i<valueS1.length; i++)
        {
            myOutWriter.append(valueS1[i]);
            myOutWriter.append(";\n");
        }

        myOutWriter.close();
        fOut.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {

    }

    /////////eijade file txt Masirha ta inja*/



    /////////eijade file txt Moshtari
    File myFile1 = new File(sdcard,"Mosh.txt"); //sabt file to sdcard
    try
    {
        String[] valueS1 = new String[] { "1 - علی احمدی - خ شيخ مفيد ک سعدي - 7896541;10,000,000;20,000,000;0;2000;علی احمدی;1;",
                "2 - علی احمدپور - خ شيخ مفيد ک سعدي - 7896541;1,000;2;0;2;علی احمدپور;2;",
                "3 - علی احمدپور - خ شيخ مفيد ک سعدي - 7896541;10787800;20,45500;0;20450;علی احمدپور;3;",
                "4 - اصغر اصغری - خ شيخ صدوق ک علامه - 9875236;123456;654321;1478523;0;اصغر اصغری;4;",
                "5 - علی احمدی - خ شيخ مفيد ک سعدي - 7896541;10,000,000;20,000,000;0;2000;علی احمدی;5;",
                "6 - اصغر اصغری - خ شيخ صدوق ک علامه - 9875236;123456;654321;1478523;0;اصغر اصغری;6;"};
        myFile1.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile1);
        OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter =new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
        for (int i=0; i<valueS1.length; i++)
        {
            myOutWriter.append(valueS1[i]);
            myOutWriter.append(";\n");
        }
        myOutWriter.close();
        fOut.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {

    }
    /////////eijade file txt Moshtari ta inja */



    //////// Ejade File txt Kala 
    File myFile2 = new File(sdcard,"Kala.txt"); //sabt file to sdcard
    try
    {
        String[] valueS1 = new String[] { "1 - Keyk - keyke yazdi - duneyee - basteyee - 5000 - 50;50;Keyk;1;","2 - Tanagholat - pastil - basteyee - kilooye - 20000 - 4000;4000;Tanagholat;2;",
                "3 - Keyk - keyke yazdi - duneyee - basteyee - 5000 - 50;50;Keyk;3;","4 - Tanagholat - pastil - basteyee - kilooye - 20000 - 4000;4000;Tanagholat;4;"};
        myFile2.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile2);
        OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter =new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
        for (int i=0; i<valueS1.length; i++)
        {
            myOutWriter.append(valueS1[i]);
            myOutWriter.append(";\n");
        }
        myOutWriter.close();
        fOut.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {

    }


    File myFile3 = new File(sdcard,"KalaGorooh.txt"); //sabt file to sdcard
    try
    {
        String[] valueS1 = new String[] { "Keyk;","Tanagholat;"};
        myFile3.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fOut1 = new FileOutputStream(myFile3);
        OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter1 =new OutputStreamWriter(fOut1);
        for (int i=0; i<valueS1.length; i++)
        {
            myOutWriter1.append(valueS1[i]);
            myOutWriter1.append("\n");
        }
        myOutWriter1.close();
        fOut1.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {

    }
    ////// Ejade File txt Kala tainja*/ 

}

public void SabteDataBase()
{
    final android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase  myDB= this.openOrCreateDatabase("DB_Bazaryab", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    /////////  Ejade DB va Table 
    ////////   khundane file text baraye masirha va Ejade Table
    try 
    {

        File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File file = new File(sdcard,"Mas.txt");
        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            text.append(line);
        }
        String TableName = "Tbl_Masir";
        String[] valueS = text.toString().split(";");
        myDB.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Tbl_Masir");
     // "IF NOT EXIT" ro baraye test bardashtam
        myDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE Tbl_Masir (id int, Address VARCHAR);");
        for (int i=0; i<valueS.length; i++)
        {

        myDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO "
                 + TableName
                 + " (id, Address)"
                 + " VALUES ("+ Integer.toString(i)+",'"+valueS[i] + "');");
        }

    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {

    }
    ////////khundane file text baraye masirha va Ejade Table ta inja */



     ////////khundane file text baraye Moshtari va Ejade Table
    try 
    {
        File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File file = new File(sdcard,"Mosh.txt");
        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            text.append(line);
        }

        myDB.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Tbl_Moshtari");
        String[] valueS = text.toString().split(";");
     // "IF NOT EXIT" ro baraye test bardashtam
        myDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE Tbl_Moshtari (id int, Info VARCHAR,Et_Naghd VARCHAR,Et_Chek VARCHAR,Mande_Bedehi VARCHAR, Cheke_Bargashti VARCHAR,Name_Moshtari VARCHAR,Code_Moshtari VARCHAR);");
        int k=0;
        for (int i=0; i<valueS.length; i=i+8)
        {
        myDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO Tbl_Moshtari (id, Info, Et_Naghd, Et_Chek ,Mande_Bedehi ,Cheke_Bargashti , Name_Moshtari, Code_Moshtari)  VALUES ("+ Integer.toString(k)+",'"+valueS[i] + "','"+ valueS[i+1]+"','"+valueS[i+2] +"','" +valueS[i+3]+"','"+valueS[i+4] +"','"+valueS[i+5] +"','"+valueS[i+6] +"');");
        k++;
        }
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {

    } 


    ////////khundane file text baraye Moshtari va Ejade Table  ta inja*/ 

     ////////khundane file text baraye Kala va Ejade Table
    try 
    {

        File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File file = new File(sdcard,"Kala.txt");
        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            text.append(line);
        }
        String TableName = "Tbl_Kala";
        String[] valueS = text.toString().split(";");
        myDB.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Tbl_Kala");
     // "IF NOT EXIT" ro baraye test bardashtam
        myDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE Tbl_Kala (id int, Kalaha VARCHAR, Gh_Vahed VARCHAR, Name_Gorooh VARCHAR, Code_Kala VARCHAR);");
        for (int i=0; i<valueS.length; i = i+5)
        {

        myDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO "
                 + TableName
                 + " (id, Kalaha, Gh_Vahed, Name_Gorooh, Code_Kala)"
                 + " VALUES ("+ Integer.toString(i)+",'"+valueS[i] +"','"+valueS[i+1]+"','"+valueS[i+2]+"','"+valueS[i+3]+ "');");
        }

    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {

    }


    try 
    {

        File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File file = new File(sdcard,"KalaGorooh.txt");
        StringBuilder text1 = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line;
        while ((line = br1.readLine()) != null) {
            text1.append(line);
        }
        String TableName = "Tbl_KalaGorooh";
        String[] valueS = text1.toString().split(";");
        myDB.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Tbl_KalaGorooh");
     // "IF NOT EXIT" ro baraye test bardashtam
        myDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE Tbl_KalaGorooh (id int, Name_Gorooh VARCHAR);");
        for (int i=0; i<valueS.length; i++)
        {

        myDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO "
                 + TableName
                 + " (id, Name_Gorooh)"
                 + " VALUES ("+ Integer.toString(i)+",'"+valueS[i] + "');");
        }

    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {

    }

    ////////khundane file text baraye Kala va Ejade Table ta inja */





}
 public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        ArrayList<Activity> activities=new ArrayList<Activity>();
        activities.remove(this);
    }
```

}

Comment: override `onBackPressed` in second activity.

Comment: onBackPressed is good,but I think you have to show some codes so we can help you..

Comment: Post some code which make sense to understand your white screen issue.

Comment: other wise check your first activity.you may finish the activity or do some destroing codes in your onPause() which cause the activity to destory.if m right then delete these things.

Comment: The white screen issue may be happening because you might be doing some time consuming tasks in your application's Main thread while coming back into the first activity. Please post some code then only one will be able to provide solution.

Comment: Hey,post your startactivty code here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first activity just write this code on action 
Intent i = new Intent (this,SecoundActivity.class);
startactivity(i);

In secound activity on back pressed just do

finish();

this code is working fine and i didnt get any white screen i think u use any third activity between this two activity and not taking any setcontentview in that third activity so that u see a white screen while you pressed back button

Comment: I use animation in my activity. i do what you write but again it doesn't work for me

Comment: what u want to do dear..just tell then i will tell proper way for that

Comment: when i go to 2nd activity and i press back button in my tablet it takes too lung and have delay. i don't want delay

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the delay is in your first activity; something in onResume is taking a while to finish. This will look like the back button is taking a while to execute but it's actually the first activity trying to load that causes the delay.

Solution:
Fire off the long-running process in an AsyncTask. You can put a loading bar or some sort of "Please Wait" dialog while the process is loading -- or if you don't really need it to display your UI, use placeholders and just load the data after it's done loading.

This way your onResume will return after calling execute() on the AsnycTask, and your UI will instantly show. The data to be loaded can come in later.